# How to solve for $\overline{x}$ in equations containing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having a little trouble in understanding how to solve for variable $\overline{x}$ in equations like:

$2\left(A\overline{x}+\overline{b}\right)=\overline{x}$ (1)

(for which I know the answer is $\overline{x}=-2\left(2A-I\right)^{-1}\ \overline{b}$, but I don't understand where the identity matrix comes from.)

$A\overline{x}=B\overline{x}+3\overline{x}$   (2)

$\overline{x}(A-B-3)=0$

(is as far as I've gotten with this one.)

and

$x^Tx=0$ (3)

The professors instructions state that (these are translated, so I apologize for any errors): we assume that all calculations are valid: $\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{b}∈\mathbb{R}^{n×1}$; matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are non-singular square matrices and the solution is unambiguous (which means that the necessary inverse matrices exist):

I'm familiar with how to solve $\overline{x}$ in

$$A\overline{x}\ =\ \overline{b}$$

$$\overline{x}\ =\ A^{-1}\overline{b}$$

and identity matrices $I$, but I can't really make heads or tails of how to to go about solving equations like (1),(2) and (3) that I listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\left(A\overline{x}+\overline{b}\right)=\overline{x}$$
$$2A\overline{x}+2\overline{b}=\overline{x}$$
$$2A\overline{x}-\overline{x}=-2\overline{b}$$
$$(2A-I)\overline{x}=-2\overline{b}$$

Comment: @Quak The remaining part is something you are familiar with. :-)